# Troubleshooting WordPress version N.N - Master List

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Regularly, I find myself doing the same comment: "Have you already done a [full troubleshooting](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/troubleshooting-wordpress-34-master-list)?"

In this [Question](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/57442/12615) I made the following one that brought me to the Meta:

[image]

---

So, **ain't nothing we can officially do to promote all the effort Ipstenu puts in her Master Lists?**

Specially when there's a new WordPress release and this Stack gets flooded with "*updated to 3.x and yyyyy is not working?*" type of questions...

Also, should I have flagged the Question as *too localized*?

Comment: How many different questions about version specific upgrade problems are on our site?

Comment: Gee, haven't counted... Or are you saying that, at the end, it doesn't matter?... Or is this a proposal of doing a metrics on the subject?

Comment: I just don’t see any reason for premature optimization. :) And if I remember this right there were not too many questions about this.

Comment: I like that: "*premature optimization*" :) - Ok, it was just a feeling of "damn, can't the same copy/paste comment be automated in the system somehow..."

Answer (score 4):

Well, once again, StackApps comes to rescue:
https://stackapps.com/q/2116/10590

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Not sure about promote, since we don't really have mechanism for such for external content.

As for question - it is too localized, but more in hindsight. In general questions, that are extremely specific to some version of WP, are considered too localized, but it's not always possible to determine if that is the case outright.

Comment: Well, yes... even having "*Provide details. Share your research. Read the FAQ*" in the HOW TO ASK box doesn't prevent the opposite behavior... I guess I'll settle with some Clipboard Favorite Texts (FAQ and Troubleshoot) and go pasting :)

Answer (score 3):

For this specific class of question, i.e. *Troubleshooting for updating from WordPress X.X to WordPress X.Y*, why not just **Ask and answer your own question for this topic**, and then redirect future duplicates to that question?

This way, the question can be kept up-to-date within the current WordPress version, answers can be added as necessary for new types of troubleshooting (or whatever), and once the next version of WordPress comes out, the process is repeated, and the old question fades quietly into the night...